# how to calculate the 5th date from a date in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a date in a javascript variable

```
var cDate='07/21/2012'  `(mm/dd/YYY format)`
```

I need to find out the 5th day from the date in `cDate Variable`

ie newDate=`'07/26/2012'`

suppose if the `cDate='07/28/2012'   then  newDate='08/2/2012'`
But I did know how. I have tried a lot and searched but my result is wrong.

Please replay

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

```
myDate = new Date(2012, 07, 28)
new Date(myDate.getTime() + 5*24*60*60*1000);
```

OR extend the Date Class as

```
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
    this.setDate(this.getDate() + days);
    return this;
};
```

Or you can even use this library. http://www.datejs.com/

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following?

```
cDate = new Date(2012, 07, 28)
cDate.setDate(cDate.getDate() + 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
var myDate=new Date();
myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate()+5);
```